# Rate at which to query asynchronous web services?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

I am using the requests package in python to query an asynchronous web service that is performing some processing for me.  How do I determine the optimal interval to wait between checks on the status of the processing?  Do you need to generate a distribution of typical wait times, for some typical processing requests?  If you generated such a data set, would it be useful?

**Edit:**

As you can probably see from this [documentation](http://www.epa.gov/waterdata/results-queue-service), there doesn't appear to be a call back option regarding this service that would let me know the processing is complete.

Here is a histogram showing the distribution of wait times (in seconds) between the initial request and the completion of the processing:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, asynchronous operations should provide some signal that they've finished, so it shouldn't be necessary to poll them. Check the documentation to see if a call-back function can be invoked when the request has completed.

If you have no choice but to poll, then the objective is to minimize the latency on accepting the response, while not unduly loading the service by excessive polling. The appropriate ratio will depend on the relative cost of servicing the actual request vs the cost of servicing a poll.

Services where the response time depends primarily on how many other requests are queued tend to have response times that follow a Poisson distribution, but other distributions are also possible.

In most cases, there is little point even starting to poll until you're near the mean response time.

These might be useful:

- Record the timing of recent queries, to use for estimating future requests (mean, stddev, and "fit" for various distributions including Poisson)
- Use a back-off strategy that matches the expected distribution; often that means an exponential back-off. Doubling is easy to compute but a bit coarse; the golden mean (Φ=(1+√5)/2) is a good general-purpose ratio, but you might be able to do better for your particular application.
- What is an acceptable failure rate due to expired queries?
- Does the underlying system have a reasonable method for cancelling in-progress queries, or do they just continue to run on the server soaking up resources?)

Comment: Welcome to SO and nice first post! My only suggestion to improve you answer would be to consider including links to things you talk about. Overall, good job though and again, welcome.

Comment: Added some edits to address some aspects of the answer.

Comment: Yep, looks pretty _Poissonish_, with an offset of about 3 seconds -- presumably the minimum time to answer a query when unloaded.